# How can one define a covariant rate of change of rest mass for an extended body?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, mass, mass-energy

For a point mass I can define a covariant rate of change of its rest mass as $\frac{d}{d\tau}m_0$ where $\tau$ is the proper time. How can I also define a covariant rate of change of rest mass for an extended body, bearing in mind that different parts will have different world lines and hence proper times?

Comment: The question seems to be asking for the impossible. As you say, there is no single preferred definition of the proper time. Even if general relativity weren't involved, this notion doesn't make sense unless you pick a frame of reference. Do you want to use the body's center of mass frame? If so, then doesn't this become trivial?

Comment: @BenCrowell IMO the rest mass of an extended body is its energy in its center of momentum frame; and its proper time would be defined here also. How correct this is, if at all, together with other possibilities is what I'm looking for in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The covariant rate of change can be obtained by a covariant time derivative operator defined by $$\frac{D}{D\tau}=u^\mu\nabla_\mu$$ where $u^\mu$ is the 4-velocity.
In flat space-time, this definition reduces to $$\frac{d}{d\tau}=u^\mu\partial_\mu$$

**PROOF:**

For an arbitrary scalar $\phi$, we can write $$u^\mu\partial_\mu\phi=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\frac{dx}{d\tau}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}+\frac{dy}{d\tau}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}+\frac{dz}{d\tau}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\\ \qquad\qquad=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}+\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}+\frac{dz}{dt}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\right)$$

The expression inside the brackets can be written as a total derivative using the definition of the material derivative:$$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla$$ So, the above equation reduces to  $$u^\mu\partial_\mu\phi=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$$

When the scalar $\phi$ is the rest mass, we have
$$\frac{dm_0}{d\tau}=u^\mu\partial_\mu m_0$$
**NOTE**:

1. The material derivative takes care of the varying proper time and varying local mass density (if the mass density is not uniform) of the various parts of the extended object.
2. The above calculation is valid not only for a scalar, but also for tensors.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question, which is about the lack of a uniquely defined proper time.